# Clicking link after search results

Tags: html, xpath, imacros

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>LICENSED CLINICAL SOCIAL WORKER</td>
        <a href="/LicenseSearch/IndividualLicense/SearchResultsSummary?chid=666783">JOE L BLACK</a><td></td>
        <td>ISLAND WI</td>
        <td>08/03/1993</td>
            <td>02/28/2017</td>
    </tr>
```

PATH ON WEBSITE::

```
body > div.main > div:nth-child(3) > div.large-12.columns > table > tbody > tr > a
```

I need to click on the link that's in `<a href="/LicenseSearch/IndividualLicense/SearchResultsSummary?chid=666783">` but I can't seem to get the loop to click on it. Can someone help me?

Tried these codes, none have worked so far:

```
TAG SELECTOR="HTML>body>div.main>div:nth-child(3)>div.large-12.columns>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3)>a:nth-child(1)"

EVENTS TYPE=DBLCLICK SELECTOR="(/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[contains(@href)" BUTTON=0

TAG XPATH="/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a"

TAG XPATH="(/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[contains(@href))"
```

Comment: Did you try like so: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/LicenseSearch/IndividualLicense/SearchResultsSummary` ?

Comment: I just did, sadly it doesn't work. I won't click on the link